# Div does not refresh when last character is deleted from input

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I'm currently making a search function using a `onkeyup="Search();"` like this:

```
<input type="text" id="IDsearch" onkeyup="Search()" autofocus>
```

The function for it is:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function Search() {
        var inputVal = $('#IDsearch').val();

        $.post('searchTest.php', {postname: inputVal},
        function (data) {
            $('#IDsearch').val(data)
        });
        $('#divRefresh').load('searchTest.php');
    }

</script>
```

Yes, I am using the same file to both put the value in a php `$_SESSION['value'];` AND to store the new div data. That's no problem, it works, it does fine.

But when I delete my last character from my search box, I need to press backspace twice in order for my div to update.

Say I had a textbox with "a" in it. I will press backspace to update the a, and nothing will happen. Once I press backspace again, my div will update and post all the original values again.

Am I missing something obvious?
It's supposed to work the same way http://www.datatables.net/ does.

I have asked a question about this program before, but not about this issue, I hope it's not a problem.

Comment: The problem maybe because of the implementation of onkeyup from browsers. You should try to use `keyup()` from  jQuery, it might work. http://api.jquery.com/keyup/ .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would go throught `$("#IDsearch").keyup(function(){});`

Tried your code with the function and didn't work, even with `$("#divRefresh").html(theInputOfYours);` The other way I mention to you works perfectly, even with backspace.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#IDsearch").keyup(function() {
        var value = $(this).val();
        var posting = $.post("your_php_file.php", {val: value})
        posting.done(function( data ) {
            $( "#divRefresh" ).html(data);
        });
    });
});
```

The posting is a very basic example I can give, I use to go with $.ajax() function

Comment: I've never really done jQuery, where do I add the load exactly? It looks like you refresh the div with the same value every time

Comment: updated, please, if someone notices something wrong with $.post(), let me know to update it. Give a try with that.

Comment: Nope.. It should, but it doesn't.

Comment: If without `$.post` is working well, making `$("#divRefresh").html($(this).val());`, then there's something wrong, maybe, with your php file, make sure you `echo` the result you want to show. As far as I know, that simple piece of code should work. If someone else points something wrong in it, comment it to so I can edit it.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, the behavior of keyup/keypress/keydown can be finicky sometimes, especially across different browsers.

A possible solution to ensure changes are tracked would be a listener that would track changes via a `setInterval` function that runs at an interval you specify.

Comment: That seems a bit bloating for your web page though, doesn't it? "Check this content every second"?

Comment: You can try the jQuery solution if that concerns you, but just know that it won't work if users cut/paste. Also, consider how well your browser performs when it sees an animated gif. It's doing a lot more processing than just checking a field every 200 milliseconds or so.